# Issue in installing Discovery service (SDL Web 8.5)

Tags: web8.5, discovery-service

I am running this powershell script `.\quickinstall.ps1 -enable-discovery -enable-context -enable-deployer-combined -enable-preview -enable-session -auto-register -discovery-url http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc` in single machine but I am getting below error message in log files.

> ERROR RetryPoolingDataSource - Passing exception to the caller. Attempt:0 Message:Login failed for user 'TridionBrokerUser'.

I can able to connect DB with credentials in SQL studio management successfully but I am getting when running the powershell scripts.

**setenv.psl**

```
# Content
$delivery_vars["CONTENT_DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME"] = "(Servername)\SQLEXPRESS"
$delivery_vars["CONTENT_DEFAULT_PORT_NUMBER"] = "1433"
$delivery_vars["CONTENT_DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME"] = "Tridion_Broker"
$delivery_vars["CONTENT_DEFAULT_USER"] = "TridionBrokerUser"
$delivery_vars["CONTENT_DEFAULT_PASSWORD"] = "password-1"
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: double check the `setenv.ps1` file values once again, also verify where you are running the powershell script that machine has a connectivity to SQL server with that credentials, SQL server DNS name is resolving correctly or not

Comment: could you **edit** your question and provide some more details about your database, like is it a SQL Server named instance and is it using a standard port? You might also want to take a look at https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14136/connect-to-sql-server-using-named-instances

Comment: server-name, confirm whether its default/named instance etc and database name. are you able to connect to DB from this serverx using some basic tool  e.g http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx

Comment: @RajKumar it's the default instance. i can able to connect to DB using SQL mgmt studio.

Comment: @user2389 - Are you able to login as "TridionBrokerUser" using SQL Management studio and see all the tables of Tridion_Broker DB?

Comment: **@Rajesh:** I can able to view the tables in SQL mgmt studio.

Comment: You mean SQL studio management is installed on the same server where the micro services you are trying to install, SQL DB also on the same server or it's different server, try to install only content service instead of installing all the services by one command

Comment: are you able to connect to DB server from your CD machine?

Comment: @user2389. Connect to SQL server MMC settings and go to the protocols for MSSQL server. Click on TCP/IP and go to the ip address tab.  check if 1433 port is mentioned for all the active IP adress. Let me know if this helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: From powershel, run - 
"Test-NetConnection -ComputerName db-server-name.com -Port 1433"
If "TcpTestSucceeded : True" then your connection to db is fine..
Seeing the error "Login failed for user 'TridionBrokerUser'." It more likely seem to me that your db is reachable. Check credentials properly.